# Conceptual difficulty with Newton's third law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Consider a block of mass $M$. I provide a force $F$<sub>m</sub> as shown in the picture below. Considering frictional force to be $F$<sub>f</sub> and reactional force to be $F$<sub>r</sub>, what will be the net force on the block (more specifically why). As per my understanding, $F$<sub>m</sub>$=$- $F$<sub>r</sub>, thus they cancel to zero.
I know there are several similar questions on PSE, but none really worked up for me.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by reactional force

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You toil under a common misconception [regarding Newton's Third Law](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zqs47p3/revision/4#:%7E:text=According%20to%20Newton%27s%20third%20law,an%20equal%20and%20opposite%20reaction%27.):

> According to Newton's third law of motion, whenever two objects
> interact, they exert equal and opposite forces on each other.
>
> This is often worded as 'every action has an equal and opposite
> reaction'. However, it is important to remember that the two forces:
>
> - act on two different objects
> - are of the same type (eg both contact forces)

Here the two bodies are the mass and the Earth. The force acts on the mass and an equal, reactive force acts in the opposite reaction on the Earth.

$\text{N2L}$ applies:

as long as
$$F_f-F_m=0$$

there will be no motion. Only when $F_m$ exceeds $F_f$ will the mass start to slide (experience acceleration)

Comment: The Earth? How is the Earth relevant? The. applied force is horizontal.

Comment: Friction acts horizontally. Without it no one would be able to stand up, never mind walk or run.

Comment: The problem is not about friction.  He thinks that the reaction force to the applied force Fm acts on the same body and cancel each other out.  Which is not the case.

Comment: I quote:  *Considering frictional force to be $F_f$ and reactional force to be $F_r$, what will be the net force on the block* Why not formulate your own answer?

Comment: He means reaction to Fm and not to the friction.  This is why he writes Fr=-Fm.  The reaction to friction will be in opposite direction, not in the direction of friction force.   He gets the "opposite and equal" part of the law.  The usual mistake is assuming they act on the same body.

Comment: @Gert Where does $F$r go?

Comment: @Eisenstein $F_r$ *as you see it* doesn't exist. Imagine we place the block on a table. Now we push it horizontally with $F_m$ and there's friction between the block and the table, preventing the block from moving. Now a reactive force (call it what you want e.g. $R$) must act *on the table* to prevent it from moving. Of course you can apply the same reasoning to the system block+table/floor (Earth)